# Accessing the application default root path through language preferences does not work

Tags: next.js, i18next, react-i18next

A minimized NEXT13 project with an i18n configuration.
How to jump to a different root page by language preference access "localhost:3000/" path?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvgcw.png)

question:https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/57861

Now,access localhost:3000/,It is show English root page,But my browser language setting is Chinese,
Displays the content in accordance with the current browser locale

Comment: The easiest way I could think of is to config your `i18n.js` file with `i18next-browser-language-detector` plugin: [i18next-browser-languageDetector](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector)

Comment: Just for advises, please provide direct code samples so we can understand what you have done. It is also not the best practice to require someone to look into other website's discussions.